# MySQL table must contain between 80 and 100 rows

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

For a school assignment, I need to have a MySQL table that contains between 80 and 100 rows (inclusive). A cron job enters a row into the table every 2 hours. I wanted to do this with triggers, but apperantly this is not possible because the table is locked because of the INSERT statement. This was the trigger I used:

```
CREATE TRIGGER too_many_rows
BEFORE INSERT ON log
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM log) >= 100 THEN
        DELETE FROM log LIMIT 1;
    END IF;
END
```

The tricky part is that there are also manual inserts on the table, which is the reason why I can't periodically check (CRON jobs or MySQL events) if there are too many tables because at some point there might be too many rows. The ideal situation would be to remove the oldest row every time a new row is added.

Is there any way I could still do this?

Comment: Do you have control over the inserts? If so you could just tell your cron job to update (overwrite everything but the id) the oldest entry (using a timestamp field).

Comment: Why not have a table of 100 rows, and then only execute UPDATES?

Comment: I do not have control over the periodic updates. It is a specific user from a specific IP address that has only INSERT and SELECT privileges. It issues an INSERT every 2 hours.

Comment: Would it be possible to prevent the INSERT using a trigger, and do an update on the oldest entry instead?

Comment: Are you sure you understood the task correctly (or aren't missing important details)? It might be e.g. a "should", and you are just required to run a cronjob to clean up. "must" usually means that if the constraint isn't fulfilled, the data becomes invalid (like foreign or unique keys). Does the number of rows have any logical meaning in the data model? Does a query break? Enforcing a random row limit on a log table with only insert/select-permissions (and can't skip the insert?) sounds, even if doable, like you would only learn how not to design a database (especially in an exercise).

Comment: The task says "should", but an automatic checking script fails, saying the table isn't "between 80 and 100 rows". The only thing we need to be able to do with the data is display the last entry on a website. The row limit is indeed random...

Comment: Either have a) an event/cronjob that runs regularly and cleans up, and 80-100 rows would give an estimate about how often (e.g. if your users create approx 120 rows per hour, run it every 10 minutes). Or b) let inserts happen via a procedure (that also cleans up). Or c) if *just* the cron job can't use a procedure but all other sources can, have a procedure and a 2-hour-event that both limit to 99 rows; then one insert every 2 hours will get you at most to 100 rows. Which one fits best would depend on context, usual type of assignment and "checking script".

Comment: And to stretch it again: this is, in its hard form (a hard limit on the number of rows in a log table, with an unmodifyable cronjob without permissions that has to insert into *that* table (e.g. you can't just use a different table where you copy it into)) is a completely unrealistic requirement. So you either misunderstood something or it is specifically designed to point you to some specific way to do it or to combine specific elements of the task (see e.g. point c in my previous comment). If you know how the checking script works (or worked in previous tasks), it might give you a hint.

Comment: Are you supposed to delete some arbitrary row?  Or the oldest row?  Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what I am looking for is not really possible, and so I used a MySQL event to remove redundant rows every hour.

Here is the code:

**EVENT check_for_redundant_rows**

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT check_for_redundant_rows
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
STARTS '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
DO
CALL delete_redundant_rows();
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**PROCEDURE delete_redundant_rows()**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE delete_redundant_rows()
BEGIN
    DECLARE cnt INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT COUNT(id)
    INTO cnt
    FROM log;

    SET cnt = cnt - 80;

    DELETE FROM log
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT cnt;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a trigger to do this. I would do it with a transaction called from application code.

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO log ...;
SELECT id INTO @id FROM log ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 100;
DELETE FROM log WHERE id <= @id;
COMMIT;
```

If there are fewer than 100 rows in the table, it will assign NULL to `@id`, and the DELETE will delete no rows.

If there are more than 100 rows in the table, it will assign to `@id` the id of the row 100 rows from the end. Then the DELETE will delete that row and any earlier rows, leaving just 100 rows. Using this multi-step method is better than just deleting where id < max - 100, because you shouldn't assume there are no missing id values.

There's a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) if you have multiple clients doing this at the same time. That is, it's possible that two concurrent sessions will both be selecting and deleting. This could result in the total number of rows being more than 100 temporarily, at least until the next time a row is inserted and extra rows deleted.

Comment: Thank you Bill! However, the I don't have controll over the INSERTs. They will happen, so I need a way to trigger the code that removes the oldest rows whenever an INSERT happens...